# Can this XPath expression be minified

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I'm not an XPath expert and I couldn't find a tool to do this. Is there a way to minify this XPath statement? 80% is redundant.

**XPATH 2**

```
 (//CustomField | //fields)[
     (fullName/text[not(matches(@Image, "chk_[a-zA-Z0-9]+__c"))] and type/text[@Image="Checkbox"]) or
     (fullName/text[not(matches(@Image, "txt_[a-zA-Z0-9]+__c"))] and type/text[@Image="Text"]) or
     (fullName/text[not(matches(@Image, "txa_[a-zA-Z0-9]+__c"))] and type/text[@Image="Textarea"]) or
     (fullName/text[not(matches(@Image, "txr_[a-zA-Z0-9]+__c"))] and type/text[@Image="Richtext"]) or
     (fullName/text[not(matches(@Image, "txl_[a-zA-Z0-9]+__c"))] and type/text[@Image="LongTextArea"]) or
     (fullName/text[not(matches(@Image, "num_[a-zA-Z0-9]+__c"))] and type/text[@Image="Number"]) or
     (fullName/text[not(matches(@Image, "dat_[a-zA-Z0-9]+__c"))] and type/text[@Image="Date"]) or
     (fullName/text[not(matches(@Image, "lkp_[a-zA-Z0-9]+__c"))] and type/text[@Image="Lookup"]) or
     (fullName/text[not(matches(@Image, "mdr_[a-zA-Z0-9]+__c"))] and type/text[@Image="MasterDetail"]) or
     (fullName/text[not(matches(@Image, "dtm_[a-zA-Z0-9]+__c"))] and type/text[@Image="DateTime"]) or
     (fullName/text[not(matches(@Image, "url_[a-zA-Z0-9]+__c"))] and type/text[@Image="Url"]) or
     (fullName/text[not(matches(@Image, "pkl_[a-zA-Z0-9]+__c"))] and type/text[@Image="Picklist"]) or
     (fullName/text[not(matches(@Image, "pkm_[a-zA-Z0-9]+__c"))] and type/text[@Image="MultiselectPicklist"]) or
     (fullName/text[not(matches(@Image, "cur_[a-zA-Z0-9]+__c"))] and type/text[@Image="Currency"]) or
     (fullName/text[not(matches(@Image, "pct_[a-zA-Z0-9]+__c"))] and type/text[@Image="Percent"]) or
     (fullName/text[not(matches(@Image, "fcur_[a-zA-Z0-9]+__c"))] and type/text[@Image="Currency"] and formula) or
     (fullName/text[not(matches(@Image, "rcnt_[a-zA-Z0-9]+__c"))] and type/text[@Image="Summary"] and summaryOperation/text[@Image="count"]) 
]
```

**This is a stripped down version of an XML document with one match**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

    <fields>
        <fullName>txl_Description__c</fullName>
        <deprecated>false</deprecated>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>Price Schedule Description</label>
        <length>4000</length>
        <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>LongTextArea</type>
        <visibleLines>5</visibleLines>
    </fields>
    <fields>
        <fullName>Reason_For_Override__c</fullName>
        <deprecated>false</deprecated>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>Reason for Override</label>
        <length>1000</length>
        <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>LongTextArea</type>
        <visibleLines>2</visibleLines>
    </fields>
</CustomObject>
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant sample of the XML and so complete a [mcve]? The sample could be minimized, but to check it, we need the XML...

Comment: So, you want `<fullName>Reason_For_Override__c</fullName>` to match and `<fullName>txl_Description__c</fullName>` to be ignored? Is that right?

Comment: Yes the matching token is the field name that does not obey they naming convention where there is a specific type prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thoroughly checked your expression and it looks like that there is near zero redundancy. The part `_[a-zA-Z0-9]+__c` is of low relevance in optimizing the expression.

Creating tuples like `("chk","Checkbox")` and `("txt","TextBox")` will neither improve readability nor performance, even if it seems like that. So you're good to go, AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace all those occurrences of `text()` with `.`, which is better practice anyhow.

You could pass in a parameter `$data` containing a lookup table: `<data><key a="chk" b="Checkbox"/><key a="..." b="..."/>...</data>` and then do

```
some $key in $data/data/key 
satisfies fullName[not(matches(., concat($key/@a, "_[a-zA-Z0-9]+__c"))] 
          and type[.=$key/@b])
```

Comment: can you check my changed XPath above. Replacing text with . didnt work at all.

Comment: No, sorry. I hate the fact that SO allows you to change a question after it has been correctly answered, thus invalidating the original answer, and it's a game I'm not prepared to play.